# cant install ROS on VirtualBox/Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.
I've tried to install ROS for the last two days, followed a few guides, tried to type in the installation commands in the ubuntu terminal a thousand times.
I have virtualbox installed I have the extension packages installed I have installed ubuntu 12.04 I have checked: mail, universe, restricted and multiverse in the software sources and unchecked the installable cd/dvd. I have updated in terminal by executing the sudo apt-get update command
everytime I enter this command: "the normal installation command"
Nothing happens, just a new line with: ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ starts.

I cant post webadresses..

Another isues I also have is my keyboard has all the special signs like: _/(=&/¤*^" etc. swicted around, so I have to guess where they know are hidding even through I have my own country keyboard layout configurated, so what can that be all about?
Im so frustrated right now, so hope somebody can help me, I have tried google alot without any concrete help.
Best regards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/74800/cant-install-ros-on-virtualbox/ubuntu-12.04/) by [Dynamitetalks](https://answers.ros.org/users/6157/dynamitetalks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2013-08-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on 2013-08-26**:
can you poste might a little more information ? what is the output if you enter which command, for example "sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-desktop"

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-08-26**:
Please check the support guidelines: http://ros.org/wiki/Support to get useful help. You need to give some concrete information what you tried to do and what failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are following the guide at: http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Ubuntu

It is important that you follow all steps and in the right order. You are missing some, e.g. the apt-get update. If you follow each step, everything should go well. If there are errors, please report them here including the commands you issued.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dynamitetalks](https://answers.ros.org/users/6157/dynamitetalks/) on 2013-08-26**:
I was told at Ubuntu's forum, that I should just go to next step and keep on. it worked lol. now my problem is that I doesnt have enough space on my drive. I'll see if I can fix it by google. thanks so far for all your help! (: